# How to tell VSCode where C++ std library headers are located?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I had a good compiler toolchain set up and working in VSCode for C++. Then I moved the location of my compiler to a new folder during an update. Now during compilation I get the error :

```
cannot open source file "iostream"
```

It is obvious that VSCode can no longer find C++ std library includes.  I do not have a c_cpp_properties.json file in my project folder anywhere. It was never autogenerated (as some websites claim). There must be something on my computer somewhere that is telling VSCode to look at the old include directory from a previous compiler installation. But where is this config file and what is the filename?

Comment: Is the error from compilation or intellisense? Have you followed the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)?

Comment: c_cpp_properties.json is for the Intellisense only. tasks.json is for building. Both of these files are independent of each other.

Comment: `c_cpp_properties.json` file can just be added, and you will probably need it, I can help you further, but I need to know which compiler your using. Are you using GCC, MingW, MVSC, or somthing else?

Comment: And, just so you know, the STD Library Header files are located in their own system directory, and are not part of the VS Code file tree.